# Error mounting /dev/sdb1 at /media/ on Ubuntu 14.04 LTS

Tags: 14.04, mount

How I can fix the Error mounting /dev/sdb1 at /media/... It works pretty good in the past but I made a clean installed of Ubuntu 14.04 LTS and the Error mounting coming.
I try to fix it with with Gparted, ntfs-3g, pmount, but this programs can't find the external HDD.
But when I boot put the USB drive with Ubuntu 14.04 on test mode this can find and read my external HDD.
How I can fix it?

Answer (score 232):

open terminal with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> and run

```
sudo ntfsfix /dev/sdb1
```

Comment: before I use this command, I want to make sure it doesn't put my files already on the drive in danger. My drive is loaded with files, and worked on windows system. Now that I connect it to ubuntu, it shows me the above error. If I use the above suggested command, will it make my files inaccessible ? I understand it will make the drive usable. By also care about existing files, written by Windows.

Comment: I did this. But it gives this error  `ntfs_mst_post_read_fixup_warn: magic: 0x00000000  size: 1024   usa_ofs: 0  usa_count: 0: Invalid argument
Record 10 has no FILE magic (0x0)
Failed to open inode FILE_UpCase: Input/output error`

Comment: many thanx ace fix in 2022 on 20.04 on a caddy external which I thought might have been defunct ...   all it needed was that line ...

Comment: It worked in past, but now it gives me the same error @ThusithaSumanadasa mentioned.

Comment: Works on 20.04!

Comment: you saved my ass, thank you!

Answer (score 20):

**Run this command to show disks:**

```
lsblk
```

**Run this command to mount usb:**

```
sudo ntfsfix /dev/sdb
```

/dev/sdb or /dev/sdb1 or some other path

Answer (score 10):

I used this **ntfsfix** package to check my external drive

```
sudo ntfsfix /dev/sdb
```

But in some case this ***/dev/sdb*** can be **/dev/sda1** or **/dev/sda2**

Answer (score 1):

It might be the case that the naming changes when you try the drive on different things. ( sdb becomes sdX because of how the usbs are enumerated)
Open a terminal and play with:

```
lsblk
blkid
```

If you are still unsure, then try

```
dmesg | more
```

and read the system log, at one point you should see something similar to:

```
150289.144120] scsi 7:0:0:0: Direct-Access     WDC WD32 00BEKT-22KA9T0   01.0 PQ: 0 ANSI: 5
[150289.144951] sd 7:0:0:0: Attached scsi generic sg4 type 0
[150289.145185] sd 7:0:0:0: [sdd] 625142448 512-byte logical blocks: (320 GB/298 GiB)
[150289.145854] sd 7:0:0:0: [sdd] Write Protect is off
[150289.145863] sd 7:0:0:0: [sdd] Mode Sense: 23 00 00 00
[150289.146547] sd 7:0:0:0: [sdd] No Caching mode page found
[150289.146555] sd 7:0:0:0: [sdd] Assuming drive cache: write through
[150289.212988]  sdd: sdd4
[150289.215143] sd 7:0:0:0: [sdd] Attached SCSI disk
```

If not, then try different usb ports, some usb are full powered, some half powered, some mother board don't like usb3 devices on usb2 slots..

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I can find the sdb1 external HDD with lsblk and I can find something with dmesg | more. (How I can put screenshots here?). And what can I do now?. Greetings

Comment: It's all text, select,copy paste. You could use pastebin to plot more text and just provide a link.

Comment: Hi, I can find this with lsblk http://es.tinypic.com/view.php?pic=sziv89&s=8#.VOTtD3WG9BR. And I can find this with dmesg | more http://es.tinypic.com/view.php?pic=xleam8&s=8#.VOTtbHWG9BQ. What can I do to fix the mount of my external HDD. Greetings

Comment: Ok, it seems the system sees it as sdb1. Could you try:
`sudo mkdir /media/usb_drive ; sudo mount /dev/sdb1 /media/usb_drive`
And paste any errors that are reported.
More detail error on the mount failure will be added at the end of dmesg, if it fails

Comment: Well with sudo mkdir /media/usb_drive appears me: mkdir: can not create directory "/ media / usb_drive ': File exists  ;  and with  sudo mount /dev/sdb1 /media/usb_drive appears me: mount: / dev / sdb1 is not a valid block device

Comment: hmm, last one is interesting. What does dmesg say after you try mount. First one is fine, it's telling you that you already created the dir. Could you try:
`sudo fsck /dev/sdb1` And paste the complaint?

Comment: With Ubuntu 14.04 on test mode I can find and read my external HDD. http://es.tinypic.com/view.php?pic=df9ick&s=8#.VOUEf3WG9BQ. http://es.tinypic.com/view.php?pic=2e0jxbl&s=8#.VOUEzXWG9BQ

Comment: aha, you have ntfs.. that's why.. well, try this now.. `sudo apt-get install ntfs-3g` and then `sudo mount -t ntfs-3g /dev/sdb1 /media/usb_drive` . Linux doesn't have a good working pure ntfs driver. It uses Microsoft's very own driver to access disks through a wrapper, which is not all the time bundled with the system. In your case, you need to install it if it's missing.

Comment: With sudo fsck /dev/sdb1 appears me fsck de util-linux 2.20.1
e2fsck 1.42.9 (4-Feb-2014)
fsck.ext2: No such device or address while trying to open / dev / sdb1
Could not exist or is a swap device?

Comment: see my previous comment.

Comment: With sudo mount -t ntfs-3g /dev/sdb1 /media/usb_drive appears me:     Error opening '/dev/sdb1': No existe el dispositivo o la dirección
Failed to mount '/dev/sdb1': No such device or address
Either the device is missing or it's powered down, or you have
SoftRAID hardware and must use an activated, different device under
/dev/mapper/, (e.g. /dev/mapper/nvidia_eahaabcc1) to mount NTFS.
Please see the 'dmraid' documentation for help.; But the power is on and it is not RAID

Comment: Did you isntall the ntfs-3g package?

Comment: Then, try `sudo ntfs-3g /dev/sdb1 /media/usb_drive`

Comment: I try to mount it in the past with ntfs-3g, I have installed ntfs-3g latest version but dont works. I stored files both from windows and ubuntuat the same partition, and works pretty good with ubuntu 12.04

Comment: I ran out of ideas.. sorry.

Comment: With sudo ntfs-3g /dev/sdb1 /media/usb_drive appears me:  Error opening '/dev/sdb1': No such device or address
Failed to mount '/dev/sdb1': No such device or address
Either the device is missing or it's powered down, or you have
SoftRAID hardware and must use an activated, different device under
/dev/mapper/, (e.g. /dev/mapper/nvidia_eahaabcc1) to mount NTFS.
Please see the 'dmraid' documentation for help.

Answer (score 1):

I got the same error, but in my case, it wasn't because of a corrupted `NTFS`, but because Ubuntu didn't recognize that the disk was formatted as `exFAT`. I could open the disk with no problem in Windows. Then I checked the format and saw that it was `exFAT`. To open it in Linux I installed:

```bsh
$ sudo apt install exfat-fuse exfat-utils
```

And the disk could open without any issue.